# Matplotlib stacked and grouped histogram

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

I'm trying to compare 2 datasets with a histogram. I have a pandas dataframe which contains 3 columns: username (cleaned for anonymity), a series of lists of time frequency data, and a type column.

My goal is to make a grouped histogram with the goal of comparing the 2 different types against one another in each histogram bin, but I want each comparison bar to be a stacked bar representing the contribution of each user.

```
import pandas
import ast
generic = lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x)
aa=pd.read_csv('Data/aa.csv', header=0, names=('middle', 'name', 'type'), converters={'middle':generic, 'type':np.int64})
```

I've been able to get stacked bar charts within each type (without comparison between types):

```
plt.hist(aa[aa['type']==1]['middle'], stacked=True, bins=24) #24 bins correspond to hours, this is time frequency data
plt.title("type 1 stacked bar")
plt.show()
plt.hist(aa[aa['type']==2]['middle'], stacked=True, bins=24)
plt.title("type 2 stacked bar")
plt.show()
```

[image: type 1 stacked bar]
[image: type 2 stacked bar]

and I've also been able to get the comparison between the two types (without bar stacking):

```
aa2 = aa.explode('middle', ignore_index=True)
plt.hist((aa2[aa2['type']==1]['middle'],(aa2[aa2['type']==2]['middle'])), bins=24)
plt.title('type 1 vs type 2 stacked bar')
plt.show()
```

[image: bar comparison]

My aim is to have this last chart but with the solid orange and blue replaced with the stacks of color from the above two images. I have no intention of being able to track which user contributed where- the main thing I'm trying to capture is the number of different users who contribute to a particular bar. With this in mind, I think it'd also be nice to give an overall color palette to type 1 and type 2, if possible.

My previous tries are below:

```
plt.hist(x=(aa[aa['type']==1]['middle'], aa[aa['type']==2]['middle']), \
         stacked=True, bins=24)
plt.show()
```

```
Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[108], line 1
----> 1 plt.hist(x=(aa[aa['type']==1]['middle'], aa[aa['type']==2]['middle']), stacked=True, bins=24)

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py:2581, in hist(x, bins, range, density, weights, cumulative, bottom, histtype, align, orientation, rwidth, log, color, label, stacked, data, **kwargs)
   2575 @_copy_docstring_and_deprecators(Axes.hist)
   2576 def hist(
   2577         x, bins=None, range=None, density=False, weights=None,
   2578         cumulative=False, bottom=None, histtype='bar', align='mid',
   2579         orientation='vertical', rwidth=None, log=False, color=None,
   2580         label=None, stacked=False, *, data=None, **kwargs):
-> 2581     return gca().hist(
   2582         x, bins=bins, range=range, density=density, weights=weights,
   2583         cumulative=cumulative, bottom=bottom, histtype=histtype,
   2584         align=align, orientation=orientation, rwidth=rwidth, log=log,
   2585         color=color, label=label, stacked=stacked,
   2586         **({"data": data} if data is not None else {}), **kwargs)

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py:1433, in _preprocess_data.<locals>.inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1430 @functools.wraps(func)
   1431 def inner(ax, *args, data=None, **kwargs):
   1432     if data is None:
-> 1433         return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
   1435     bound = new_sig.bind(ax, *args, **kwargs)
...
-> 6715         xmin = min(xmin, np.nanmin(xi))
   6716         xmax = max(xmax, np.nanmax(xi))
   6717 if xmin <= xmax:  # Only happens if we have seen a finite value.

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'float'
```

and:

```
plt.hist(x=(aa2[aa2['type']==1]['middle'], aa2[aa2['type']==2]['middle']), \
         stacked=True, bins=24)
plt.show()
```

[image: stacks are of each type rather than being contributions of each type]

I think my 2 ways forward are to somehow stitch the first 2 histograms together (no idea how), or to somehow color the 3rd histogram using data from the first 2 (again, no idea how).

I'm open to other ways of presenting this data as well! Any thoughts or suggestions are welcome.

#### Data

aa.csv file linked here on pastebin: https://pastebin.com/DjLD0vbk

Following is a subset of the data (that fits in the question).

```
middle,name,type
"[8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.25, 10.75, 10.625, 10.875, 16.75, 9.25, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75]",0,1
"[8.125, 8.125, 8.125, 8.125, 8.125, 8.125, 8.125, 8.125, 8.125, 8.125, 8.125, 8.125, 8.125, 8.125, 8.125, 8.125, 8.125, 8.125, 8.125, 8.125, 8.125, 8.125, 8.125, 8.125, 8.125, 8.125, 8.125, 8.125, 8.125, 8.125, 8.125, 8.125, 8.125, 8.125, 8.125, 8.125, 8.125, 8.125, 8.125, 8.125, 8.125, 8.125, 8.125, 8.125, 8.125, 8.125, 8.125, 8.125, 8.125, 8.125, 8.125, 8.125, 8.125, 8.125, 8.125, 8.125, 8.125, 8.125, 7.875, 8.125]",1,1
"[10.25, 11.25, 6.25, 14.5, 6.75, 8.5, 8.5, 10.875, 16.5, 15.5, 10.0, 15.5, 12.5, 7.75, 9.25, 5.5, 9.75, 10.25, 5.75, 16.125, 8.5, 10.75, 7.5, 13.25, 9.125, 9.0, 7.0, 7.875, 11.0, 15.5, 6.75, 9.75, 11.0, 8.5, 8.125, 17.375, 7.125, 11.0, 15.5, 9.75, 15.25, 12.25, 10.5, 13.25, 10.0, 9.0, 16.25, 12.5, 16.5, 6.625, 10.25, 7.5, 10.75, 12.25, 10.25, 9.25, 11.25, 11.75, 10.0, 10.875, 11.0, 9.75, 14.125, 12.375, 11.625, 10.0, 10.75, 17.0, 5.75, 13.375, 16.5, 6.5, 12.5, 10.625, 9.0, 10.625, 9.375, 10.625, 9.875, 16.5, 12.875, 7.75, 8.75, 8.5, 12.0, 17.75, 14.0, 9.25, 11.5, 13.0, 10.125, 14.125, 11.25, 10.5, 7.0, 10.375, 10.5, 9.25, 7.25, 13.25, 8.75, 9.5, 6.5, 10.0, 7.5, 16.5, 10.25, 10.125, 7.375, 14.25, 6.5, 13.0, 7.5, 14.5, 10.5, 11.375, 8.5, 10.25, 10.25, 18.0, 10.25, 8.25, 11.875, 8.5, 10.75, 10.25, 18.5, 16.5, 10.25, 13.0, 10.5, 9.0, 8.5, 8.375, 9.75, 12.75, 12.125]",2,1
"[18.875, 13.625, 14.25, 6.25, 6.0, 6.25, 22.875, 22.875, 21.875, 11.875, 13.125, 19.625, 9.25, 18.75, 13.125, 9.25, 16.75, 19.0, 13.125, 6.625, 18.75, 14.875, 9.25, 5.25, 5.25, 5.25, 7.5, 5.25, 18.5, 5.25, 5.5, 8.5, 13.125, 17.625, 13.125, 7.125, 4.375, 19.5, 9.25, 18.625, 9.25, 18.25, 9.25, 8.25, 19.5, 13.125, 19.375, 9.25, 18.5, 19.0, 7.875, 9.0, 12.0]",3,1
"[19.5, 19.5, 20.375, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 20.375, 20.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 20.375, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 20.375, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 20.375, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 20.375, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 20.375, 21.375, 19.125, 20.5, 20.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 20.375, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 20.375, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 20.5, 20.5, 20.5, 20.25, 20.5, 20.875, 19.625, 20.25, 21.0, 20.25, 20.25, 20.75, 20.25, 20.25, 20.25, 20.25, 19.5, 20.25, 20.25, 19.125, 20.25, 20.25, 20.75, 19.5, 20.5, 20.5, 20.5, 20.5, 20.5, 20.5, 21.375, 22.0, 19.5, 20.5, 19.25, 20.25, 20.25, 19.25, 20.25, 20.25, 20.5, 20.25, 20.25, 20.25, 20.375, 20.25]",4,1
[17.75],5,1
"[12.5, 8.0, 13.5, 15.0, 15.75, 12.5, 12.5, 16.5, 14.0, 9.5, 12.5, 9.5, 10.5, 16.75, 13.25, 16.5, 15.5, 13.5]",6,1
"[8.75, 14.25, 8.75, 16.75, 16.75, 16.75, 8.75, 8.75, 16.75, 8.75, 16.75, 14.25, 8.75, 16.75, 8.75, 16.75, 14.25, 8.75, 16.75, 8.75, 16.75, 14.25, 14.25, 16.75, 8.75, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 8.75, 16.75, 8.75, 16.75, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 16.75, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 8.5, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 12.75, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 8.75, 16.75, 8.75, 16.75, 8.75, 16.75, 14.25, 14.25, 8.75, 16.75, 8.75, 16.75, 8.75, 16.75, 14.25, 14.75, 8.75, 16.75, 8.75, 14.25, 14.25, 8.75, 16.75, 8.75, 16.75, 14.25, 14.25, 8.75, 14.25, 16.75, 8.75, 16.75, 8.75, 16.75, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 12.375, 11.375, 17.25, 12.125, 7.0, 14.25, 15.0, 13.375, 9.375, 14.875, 7.0, 14.25, 19.75, 7.0, 13.375, 16.875, 18.625, 14.25, 14.75, 14.25, 14.75, 12.75, 7.0, 13.375, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 15.625, 17.5, 7.25, 14.25, 13.375, 14.25, 7.0, 6.75, 14.5, 9.5, 16.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 16.75, 18.625, 19.625, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 8.75, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 14.25, 16.25, 11.625, 15.5, 10.875, 11.625, 15.375, 6.375, 6.375, 6.375, 6.375, 6.375, 6.375, 6.375, 7.0, 14.25, 17.375, 6.5, 14.25, 11.125, 15.0, 16.875, 14.5, 14.25, 10.875, 12.5, 13.625, 17.375, 15.0, 6.375, 6.375]",7,1
"[11.5, 20.5, 22.25, 18.625, 3.25, 1.25, 11.25, 20.25, 20.125, 18.75, 3.0, 1.125, 23.25, 21.75, 12.375, 17.125, 21.375, 22.125, 22.75, 16.75, 16.25, 14.75, 13.375, 20.25, 12.0, 1.875, 17.5, 0.5, 12.0, 0.75, 0.5, 23.0, 3.0, 20.375, 19.625, 12.0, 15.125, 1.25, 18.625, 14.375, 13.125, 12.25, 18.875, 3.25, 0.75, 23.125, 11.5, 16.875, 16.25, 16.375, 17.875, 6.5, 14.75, 9.0, 17.0, 10.0, 13.125, 11.875, 8.75, 7.75, 7.75, 7.5, 7.75, 15.5, 10.875, 17.25, 15.0, 7.75, 18.0, 11.75, 7.75, 7.75, 18.25, 7.5, 6.5, 7.75, 7.75, 9.375, 7.75, 19.25, 18.375, 11.875, 7.75, 18.5, 7.75, 17.75, 13.125, 9.125, 5.25, 6.0, 6.75, 16.25, 10.75, 16.5, 14.0, 14.625, 16.25, 7.125, 16.75, 7.0, 19.5, 19.375, 7.75, 6.0, 11.0, 19.25, 7.0, 18.75, 8.75, 14.125, 12.875, 10.75, 18.75, 17.25, 19.375, 17.875, 7.75, 6.5, 7.75, 18.0, 11.75, 8.0, 11.75, 18.5, 14.25, 12.75, 16.75, 11.75, 12.375, 14.0, 17.5, 13.75, 13.125, 14.25, 9.375, 17.5, 17.875, 17.5, 9.875, 19.75, 17.0, 12.5, 12.125, 17.375, 14.25, 12.125, 14.75, 17.75, 11.0, 2.5, 17.25, 15.25, 13.75, 11.5, 14.5, 2.5, 17.5, 17.625, 12.125, 17.625, 17.625, 14.5, 17.625, 15.75, 8.5, 9.5, 16.875, 18.0, 9.625, 17.875, 16.75, 9.75, 14.625, 12.875, 17.25, 9.25, 17.75, 9.875, 17.875, 9.75, 18.0, 16.5, 13.5, 16.25, 20.75, 18.25, 17.25, 12.375, 16.875, 13.125, 12.125, 17.375, 14.25, 12.75, 17.875, 13.25, 12.125, 17.875, 7.625, 12.5, 18.0, 10.25, 10.125, 17.5, 14.5, 17.875, 15.375, 11.375, 10.125, 18.125, 11.125, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 11.0, 18.25, 12.875, 11.75, 19.0, 2.5, 16.375, 9.0, 10.125, 14.125, 9.0, 15.5, 2.5, 2.5, 20.875, 17.125, 17.75, 10.75, 14.75, 13.5, 16.75, 15.75, 18.75, 17.625, 15.25, 15.875, 15.875, 19.25, 10.875, 8.25, 8.125, 16.5, 15.75, 15.0, 18.875, 21.625, 8.0, 18.0, 20.625, 18.375, 13.875, 13.0, 18.625, 18.0, 17.0, 16.375, 10.25, 10.25, 22.25, 18.375, 20.25, 18.625, 20.625, 14.25, 11.25, 10.5, 16.125, 7.75, 6.5, 12.75, 11.25, 10.125, 8.125, 13.125, 11.625, 8.5, 20.25, 14.75, 7.75, 18.5, 16.875, 7.75, 15.375, 17.125, 9.5, 18.625, 7.625, 12.0, 16.25, 14.75, 10.75, 9.75, 7.5, 6.5, 17.875, 10.5, 15.0, 12.75, 10.75, 7.125, 20.25, 7.75, 17.375, 19.25, 18.25, 21.25, 18.75, 10.375, 9.5, 12.5, 11.25, 9.0, 18.375, 20.25, 17.75, 14.0, 12.625, 17.375, 15.25, 13.75, 12.5, 20.75, 10.75, 11.875, 14.0, 10.125, 10.75, 17.25, 15.375, 13.25, 7.625, 10.375, 8.125, 16.625, 17.875, 18.25, 17.625, 16.25, 12.875, 17.75, 14.5, 10.625, 17.5, 6.625, 16.75, 12.625, 11.625, 9.125, 21.5, 18.0, 12.375, 17.625, 12.0, 18.0, 17.75, 20.125, 17.875, 13.375, 6.75, 7.625, 10.75, 9.625, 8.25, 12.375, 17.5, 17.375, 17.625, 17.125, 12.5, 18.5, 17.5, 16.375, 14.75, 17.375, 10.25, 18.5, 17.5, 1.75]",8,1
"[14.5, 11.5, 11.5, 6.75, 14.5, 11.5, 11.5, 6.75, 6.75, 6.75, 14.5, 11.5, 11.5, 6.75, 14.5, 11.5, 11.5, 14.5, 14.5, 11.5, 11.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 11.5, 11.5, 6.75, 6.75, 14.5, 11.5, 11.5, 6.75, 14.5, 11.5, 11.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 11.5, 11.5, 6.75, 14.5, 11.5, 11.5, 6.75, 6.75, 14.5, 14.5, 11.5, 11.5, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 11.5, 11.5, 6.75, 14.5, 11.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 11.5, 11.5, 6.75, 14.5, 11.5, 11.5, 14.5, 6.75, 11.5, 11.5, 14.5, 6.75, 6.75, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5]",9,1
"[18.5, 11.625, 7.625, 18.5, 11.625, 7.625, 18.5, 11.625, 7.625, 18.5, 11.625, 7.625, 18.5, 11.625, 7.625, 18.5, 11.625, 7.625, 18.5, 11.625, 7.625, 12.25, 18.5, 6.625, 11.625, 7.625, 7.625, 18.5, 11.625, 7.625, 18.5, 11.625, 7.625, 18.5, 11.625, 7.625, 18.5, 11.625, 15.375, 7.625, 18.5, 11.625, 7.625, 18.5, 11.625, 7.625, 18.5, 11.625, 7.625, 18.5, 11.625, 7.625, 11.625, 18.5, 6.625, 12.25, 11.625, 7.625, 18.5, 11.625, 7.625, 18.5, 11.625, 7.625, 12.25, 6.625, 18.5, 11.625, 7.625, 18.5, 11.625, 7.625, 18.5, 11.625, 7.625, 18.5, 11.625, 7.625, 18.5, 11.625, 7.625, 18.5, 11.625, 7.625, 12.25, 6.625, 18.5, 11.625, 7.625, 18.5, 11.625, 7.625, 18.5, 11.625, 7.625, 12.625, 6.625, 18.5, 11.625, 7.625, 6.625, 12.25, 6.625, 18.5, 11.625, 7.625, 18.5, 11.625, 7.625, 18.5, 11.625, 7.625, 12.25, 18.5, 18.5, 11.625, 7.625, 18.5, 11.625, 7.625, 18.5, 11.625, 7.625, 18.5, 11.625, 7.625, 18.5, 7.625, 11.625, 18.5, 7.625, 18.5, 11.625, 7.625, 18.5, 11.625, 7.625, 18.5, 11.625, 7.625, 18.5, 11.625, 7.625, 12.25, 6.625, 18.5, 11.625, 7.625, 18.5, 11.625, 7.625, 18.5, 11.625, 7.625, 18.5, 11.625, 11.625, 7.625, 12.25, 11.625, 18.5, 11.625, 7.625, 12.25, 6.625, 18.5, 11.625, 7.625, 18.5, 11.625, 7.625, 18.5, 11.625, 7.625, 18.5, 11.625, 7.625, 18.5, 11.625, 7.625, 12.25, 6.625, 18.5, 11.625, 7.625, 7.625, 18.5, 6.625, 7.625, 18.5, 11.625, 7.625, 18.5, 11.625, 7.625, 18.5, 11.625, 7.625, 18.5, 11.625, 7.625, 18.5, 11.625, 7.625, 12.25, 6.625, 18.5, 11.625, 7.625, 18.5, 11.625, 7.625, 18.5, 11.625]",10,1
"[19.5, 4.5, 19.5, 4.5, 19.5, 4.5, 19.5, 4.5, 19.5, 4.5, 19.5, 4.5, 19.5, 4.5, 19.5, 4.5, 19.5, 4.5, 19.5, 4.5, 4.5, 19.5, 19.5, 4.5, 19.5, 4.5, 19.5, 4.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 4.5, 19.5, 4.5, 19.5, 4.5, 19.5, 4.5, 19.5, 4.5, 19.5, 4.5, 19.5, 4.5, 19.5, 4.5, 19.5, 4.5, 19.5, 19.5, 4.5, 19.5, 4.5, 19.5, 4.5, 4.5, 19.5, 19.5, 4.5, 19.5, 4.5, 19.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 19.5, 19.5, 4.5, 19.5, 4.5, 4.5, 19.5, 4.5, 19.5, 4.5, 19.5, 19.5, 4.5, 4.5, 19.5, 4.5, 19.5, 4.5, 19.5, 4.5, 4.5, 19.5, 4.5, 4.5, 19.5, 4.5, 19.5, 4.5, 19.5, 4.5, 19.5, 4.5, 19.5, 4.5, 19.5, 4.5, 19.5, 4.5, 19.5, 4.5, 19.5, 4.5, 4.5, 19.5, 4.5, 19.5, 4.5, 19.5, 19.5, 4.5, 4.5, 19.5, 4.5, 19.5, 4.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 4.5, 9.375, 19.5, 4.5, 14.5, 5.5, 19.5, 17.375, 4.5, 19.5, 17.5, 9.5, 6.75, 4.5, 19.5, 4.5]",11,1
"[6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 6.75, 14.5, 14.5, 6.75, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 14.5, 6.75, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 6.75, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 14.5, 6.75, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 6.75, 6.75, 6.75, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 14.5, 6.75, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 6.75, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 14.5, 6.75, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 11.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 14.5, 6.75, 6.75, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 14.5, 6.75, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 6.75, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 14.5, 6.75, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 6.75, 6.75, 6.75, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 14.5, 6.75, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 6.75, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 14.5, 6.75, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 6.75, 14.5, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 6.75, 6.75, 6.75, 14.5, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 6.75, 14.5, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 14.5, 6.75, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5]",12,1
"[17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5]",13,1
"[5.5, 8.0, 18.625, 5.75, 5.75, 6.375, 7.5, 6.375, 6.375, 6.375, 18.25, 5.0, 6.75, 5.5, 5.5, 5.625, 5.75, 5.625, 12.25, 7.0, 19.25, 7.25, 17.5, 19.0, 7.25, 17.5, 19.0, 7.125, 18.625, 7.5, 18.875, 7.0, 7.5, 5.75, 7.875, 6.0, 8.0, 7.0, 8.0]",14,1
"[4.875, 7.875, 4.875, 15.5, 4.875, 7.875, 7.875, 4.875, 15.5, 4.875, 13.125, 4.875, 7.875, 7.875, 4.875, 13.125, 4.875, 15.5, 4.875, 13.125, 4.875, 13.125, 4.875, 7.875, 7.875, 15.5, 4.875, 7.875, 7.875, 4.875, 15.5, 4.875, 7.875, 7.875, 4.875, 7.875, 7.875, 11.75, 10.25, 10.125, 8.75, 13.5, 7.75, 4.75, 7.5, 12.125, 7.625, 10.5, 7.625, 6.0, 5.25, 5.875, 4.75, 7.375, 7.75, 9.5, 8.75, 18.5, 4.75, 7.875, 16.75, 7.75, 4.875, 7.875, 4.875, 4.875, 15.5, 4.875, 4.875, 4.875, 7.875, 7.875, 4.875, 15.5, 5.0, 4.875, 4.875, 4.875, 7.875, 7.875, 5.5, 7.875, 8.875, 9.375, 8.875, 16.75, 5.25, 17.625, 4.75, 14.25, 10.75, 5.0, 14.25, 10.75, 5.0, 14.25, 10.75, 5.0, 5.25, 14.25, 10.75, 10.75, 5.0, 4.75, 14.25, 10.75, 5.0, 5.0, 14.25, 5.75, 5.125, 5.125, 8.0, 10.25, 4.75, 5.125, 17.875, 4.75, 10.875, 5.25, 16.25, 14.25, 5.0, 10.75, 5.0, 14.25, 10.75, 5.0, 14.25, 10.75, 5.0, 14.25, 10.75, 7.875, 4.875, 4.875, 4.875, 15.5, 4.875, 13.125, 4.875, 7.875, 7.875, 4.875, 13.125, 4.875, 15.5, 13.125, 13.125, 4.875, 13.125, 4.875, 7.875, 7.875, 4.875, 13.125, 4.875, 15.5, 4.875, 4.875, 4.875, 4.875, 7.875, 13.125, 4.875, 15.5, 4.875, 13.125, 4.875, 13.125, 4.875, 7.875, 7.875, 4.875, 13.125, 4.875, 15.5, 4.875, 13.125, 4.875, 13.125, 4.875, 7.875, 13.125, 13.125, 4.875, 4.875, 15.5, 4.875, 13.125, 4.875, 13.125, 4.875, 7.875, 7.875, 4.875, 13.125, 13.125, 13.125, 4.875, 13.125, 4.875, 11.25, 10.125, 9.625, 7.875, 4.875, 4.875, 15.5, 4.875, 4.875, 4.875, 4.875, 7.875, 7.875, 4.875, 13.125, 4.875, 15.5, 4.875, 13.125, 4.875, 13.125, 7.875, 7.875, 7.875, 4.875, 4.875, 15.5, 4.875, 13.125, 4.875, 13.125, 4.875, 7.875, 13.125]",15,1
"[7.875, 7.875, 7.875, 7.875, 7.875, 7.875, 7.875, 7.875, 11.5, 7.875, 7.875, 7.875, 7.875, 7.875, 7.875, 7.875, 7.875, 14.5, 7.875, 7.875, 7.875, 7.875, 7.875, 6.75, 7.875, 7.875, 7.875, 7.875, 7.75, 7.875, 17.5, 7.875, 7.875, 7.875, 7.875, 7.875, 7.875, 14.5, 7.875, 7.875, 7.875, 7.875, 7.875, 7.875, 7.875, 7.875, 7.875, 7.875, 6.5, 8.0, 14.5, 10.5, 6.75, 7.875, 7.875, 7.375, 8.0, 7.375, 7.375, 9.125, 9.5]",16,1
"[11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5]",17,1
"[11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5]",18,1
"[5.125, 5.125, 5.125, 5.125, 5.125, 5.125, 5.125, 5.125, 5.125, 5.125, 5.125, 5.125, 5.125, 5.125, 5.125, 5.125, 5.125, 5.125, 5.125, 5.125, 5.125, 5.125, 5.125, 5.125, 5.125, 5.125, 5.125, 5.125, 5.125, 5.125, 5.125, 5.125, 5.125, 5.125, 5.125, 5.125, 5.125, 5.125, 5.125, 5.125, 5.125, 5.125, 5.125, 5.125, 5.125, 5.125, 5.125, 5.125, 5.125]",19,1
"[8.875, 14.5, 8.875, 20.875, 14.5, 8.875, 20.875, 14.5, 8.875, 20.875, 14.5, 8.875, 20.875, 14.5, 8.875, 20.875, 20.875, 8.875, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 8.875, 20.875, 14.5, 8.875, 20.875, 8.875, 20.875, 20.875, 14.5, 8.875, 20.875, 14.5, 8.875, 14.5, 8.875, 20.875, 8.875, 8.875, 20.875, 14.5, 8.875, 20.875, 14.5, 20.875, 20.875, 14.5, 8.875, 20.875, 14.5, 8.875, 20.875, 14.5, 8.875, 14.5, 8.875, 8.875, 20.875, 14.5, 8.875, 20.875, 14.5, 20.875, 14.5, 14.5, 8.875, 20.875, 14.5, 8.875, 20.875, 20.875, 14.5, 8.875, 20.875, 20.875, 14.5, 8.875, 20.875, 14.5, 8.875, 20.875, 14.5, 8.875, 20.875, 14.5, 8.875, 20.875, 14.5, 8.875, 8.875, 14.5, 20.875, 20.875, 20.875, 14.5, 8.875, 20.875, 14.5, 8.875, 14.5, 8.875, 8.875, 20.875, 14.5, 8.875, 20.875, 14.5, 20.875, 14.5, 8.875, 14.5, 14.5, 8.875, 20.875, 14.5, 8.875, 20.875, 8.875, 8.875, 20.875, 14.5, 8.875, 20.875, 14.5, 8.875, 20.875, 14.5, 20.875, 14.5, 14.5, 8.875, 20.875, 14.5, 8.875, 20.875, 8.875, 20.875, 20.875, 14.5, 8.875, 20.875, 14.5, 8.875, 14.5, 8.875, 14.5, 20.875, 8.875, 20.875, 20.875, 14.5, 8.875, 20.875, 14.5, 8.875, 14.5, 8.875, 20.875, 14.5, 8.875, 20.875, 14.5]",20,2
"[14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 14.5, 6.75, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 6.75, 14.5, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75]",21,2
"[8.375, 6.625, 9.25, 9.25, 14.25, 8.25, 6.625, 9.25, 8.375, 8.25, 6.625, 10.875, 8.375, 10.75, 8.375, 8.25, 8.25, 6.625, 8.375, 8.25, 6.625, 8.375, 6.625, 8.25, 8.25, 9.25, 9.25, 8.25, 9.25, 7.75, 8.375, 6.625, 6.625, 9.25, 8.25, 6.625, 8.375, 8.375, 10.25, 6.625, 8.25, 8.375, 9.25, 9.25, 9.25, 6.625, 9.25, 18.0, 7.25, 8.25, 9.25, 7.75, 18.0, 8.25, 9.25, 7.25, 9.25, 9.25, 8.25, 7.75, 18.0, 8.25, 9.25, 9.25, 7.75, 9.25, 9.25, 9.25, 7.25, 8.25, 18.0, 7.75, 9.25, 9.25, 7.25, 9.25, 8.25, 18.0, 7.75, 9.25, 8.25, 9.25, 18.0, 9.25, 9.25, 7.25, 9.25, 9.25, 7.75, 18.0, 8.25, 9.25, 9.25, 7.25, 9.25, 7.75, 18.0, 8.25, 9.25, 7.25, 9.25, 8.25, 18.0, 7.75, 9.25, 9.25, 9.25, 7.25, 9.25, 8.25, 18.0, 7.75, 9.25, 9.25, 9.25, 7.25, 8.25, 9.25, 7.25, 9.25, 9.25, 7.75, 18.0, 8.25, 9.25, 9.25, 9.25, 9.25, 9.25, 7.75, 18.0, 8.25, 9.25, 9.25, 7.25, 9.25, 8.25, 9.25, 9.25, 18.0, 7.75, 9.25, 7.25, 9.25, 18.0, 7.75, 9.25, 9.25, 9.25, 7.25, 7.25, 9.25, 18.0, 18.0, 18.0, 8.25, 9.25, 7.25, 9.25, 7.75, 8.25, 9.25, 9.25, 7.25, 9.25, 9.25, 9.25, 7.75, 7.75, 9.25, 9.25, 9.25, 7.25, 9.25, 8.25, 18.0, 7.75, 9.25, 9.25, 9.25, 7.25, 9.25, 8.25, 18.0, 7.75]",22,2
"[19.375, 19.375, 19.375, 19.375, 19.375, 19.375, 19.375, 19.375, 19.375, 19.375, 19.375, 19.375, 19.375, 19.375, 10.375, 10.375, 10.375, 19.75, 19.375]",23,2
"[8.0, 17.5, 17.75, 10.5, 14.5, 16.75, 11.0, 18.5, 17.25, 17.25, 17.25, 16.0, 17.25, 17.25, 17.25, 17.25, 17.25, 17.25, 17.25, 17.25, 17.25, 17.25, 17.25, 17.25, 17.25, 17.25, 17.25, 17.25]",24,2
"[17.25, 20.0, 16.625, 12.5, 19.5, 15.75, 14.125, 21.0, 15.0, 10.75, 15.5, 11.25, 14.5, 22.0, 19.0, 10.75, 13.5, 14.25, 19.25, 16.25, 12.75, 10.25, 19.25, 10.875, 17.25, 12.0, 19.5, 16.75, 14.0, 21.0, 9.5, 20.5, 12.0, 20.25, 14.5, 14.875, 10.75, 11.5, 18.5, 13.5, 10.75, 10.75, 22.0, 19.75, 20.0, 10.75, 20.5, 13.5, 20.75, 14.0, 22.5, 22.5, 0.25, 20.625, 11.125, 19.875, 10.5, 11.0, 20.5, 19.25, 14.875, 20.0, 11.25, 14.125, 13.0, 15.375, 20.5, 13.0, 17.25, 21.25, 8.0, 14.25, 11.625, 21.25, 20.125, 19.625, 11.75, 10.75, 16.625, 2.25, 17.25, 12.5, 19.0, 16.0, 11.0, 19.5, 14.5, 14.625, 17.0, 22.5, 17.375, 21.25, 10.625, 21.5, 14.625, 9.75, 13.25, 21.5, 11.0, 18.0, 21.0, 18.0, 15.25, 21.5, 12.5, 20.375, 9.75, 12.25, 21.5, 15.125, 21.25, 11.75, 10.75, 12.25, 13.25, 15.125, 21.0, 0.25, 10.875, 9.75, 7.25, 21.5, 21.75, 9.75, 21.0, 11.375, 14.5, 21.0, 17.0, 19.0, 21.25, 10.75, 14.875, 21.5, 13.25, 18.5, 21.5, 10.0, 21.625, 11.0, 20.75, 15.25, 13.25, 20.25, 11.5, 15.5, 20.75, 13.5]",25,2
"[14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5]",26,2
"[19.5, 19.5, 19.25, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.25, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.25, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.25, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.25, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.5, 19.25, 19.5]",27,2
"[20.25, 8.25, 20.25, 8.25, 20.25, 8.25, 20.25, 8.25, 20.25, 8.25, 20.25, 8.25, 20.25, 8.25, 20.25, 8.25, 20.25, 8.25, 20.25, 8.25, 20.25, 8.25, 20.25, 8.25, 20.25, 8.25, 8.25, 20.25, 8.25, 20.25, 8.25, 20.25, 8.25, 20.25, 8.25, 20.25, 8.25, 20.25, 20.25, 8.25, 8.25, 20.25, 8.25, 20.25, 8.25, 20.25, 8.25, 20.25, 8.25, 20.25, 8.25, 20.25]",28,2
"[9.5, 22.125, 9.5, 22.125, 9.5, 22.125, 9.5, 22.125, 9.5, 22.125, 9.5, 22.125, 9.5, 22.125, 9.5, 22.125, 9.5, 22.125, 9.5, 22.125, 9.5, 22.125, 9.5, 22.125, 22.125, 9.5, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 8.5, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 10.375, 19.25, 8.5, 9.5, 22.125, 9.5, 22.125, 9.5, 22.125, 9.5, 22.125, 9.5, 22.125, 9.5, 22.125, 9.5, 22.125, 22.125, 10.375, 9.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 19.25, 10.375, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 22.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 19.25, 19.25, 19.25, 10.375, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 19.25, 10.375, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 10.375, 10.375, 19.25, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 10.375, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 9.875, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 10.375, 19.25, 19.25, 10.375, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 15.5, 10.375, 11.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 19.25, 19.25, 19.25, 19.5, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 8.5, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 10.375, 19.25, 8.5, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 8.5, 19.25, 10.375, 10.375, 10.375, 20.625, 19.25, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 10.375, 19.25, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 8.5, 9.375, 10.375, 10.375, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 19.25, 10.375, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 8.5, 8.5, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 19.25, 19.25, 19.25, 10.375, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 19.25, 10.375, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 9.125, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 22.625, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 17.875, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 11.5, 9.375, 17.875, 8.875, 19.25, 19.25, 10.375, 10.375, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 19.25, 10.375, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 19.25, 19.25, 10.375, 10.375, 13.5, 19.25, 17.0, 10.375, 19.25, 16.0, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 10.375, 10.875, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 22.5, 19.25, 10.375, 16.5, 10.375, 19.25, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 19.25, 10.375, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 14.5, 10.125, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 19.25, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 10.375, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 23.125, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 13.25, 8.875, 19.25, 19.25, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25, 10.375, 19.25]",29,2
"[20.5, 16.25, 19.5, 20.125, 20.125, 20.125, 20.125, 20.125, 20.125, 20.125, 20.125, 20.125, 20.125, 20.125, 20.125, 20.125, 20.125, 20.125, 20.125, 20.125, 20.125, 20.125, 20.125, 20.125, 20.125, 20.125, 20.125, 20.125, 20.125, 20.125, 20.125, 20.125, 20.125, 20.125, 20.125, 20.125, 20.125, 20.125, 20.125, 20.125, 20.125, 20.125, 20.125, 20.125, 20.125, 20.125, 20.125, 20.125, 20.125, 20.125, 20.125, 20.125, 20.125]",30,2
"[15.25, 11.5, 19.5, 15.25, 11.5, 19.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5]",31,2
"[12.75, 22.5, 22.5, 16.75, 22.5, 12.75, 16.75, 22.5, 12.75, 16.75, 12.75, 12.75, 16.75, 22.5, 12.75, 16.75, 22.5, 12.75, 16.75, 22.5, 12.75, 16.75, 22.5, 22.5, 12.75, 16.75, 12.75, 16.75, 16.75, 22.5, 12.75, 16.75, 22.5, 12.75, 16.75, 22.5, 12.75, 16.75, 22.5, 12.75, 16.75, 16.75, 22.5, 12.75, 16.75, 22.5, 12.75, 16.75, 22.5, 12.75, 22.5, 16.75, 12.75, 16.75, 22.5, 12.75, 16.75, 22.5, 12.75, 16.75, 22.5, 12.75, 22.5, 16.75, 12.75, 22.5, 12.75, 16.75, 22.5, 12.75, 16.75, 22.5, 12.75, 16.75, 22.5, 12.75, 16.75, 22.5, 12.75, 16.75, 22.5, 12.75, 16.75, 22.5, 16.75, 12.75, 22.5, 12.75, 16.75, 16.75, 22.5, 12.75, 16.75, 22.5, 12.75, 16.75, 22.5, 12.75, 22.5, 22.5, 12.75, 16.75, 22.5, 12.75, 16.75, 22.5, 12.75, 16.75, 22.5, 12.75, 16.75, 16.75, 16.75, 22.5, 12.75, 16.75, 22.5, 12.75, 16.75, 22.5, 12.75, 22.5, 12.75, 12.75, 16.75, 22.5, 12.75, 16.75, 22.5, 12.75, 16.75, 22.5, 12.75, 16.75, 22.5, 12.75, 16.75, 22.5, 12.75, 16.75, 22.5, 12.75, 16.75, 22.5, 12.75, 16.75, 22.5, 12.75, 16.75, 22.5]",32,2
"[6.75, 14.5, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 14.5, 6.75, 11.5, 6.75, 14.5]",33,2
"[8.0, 7.125, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 7.125, 7.125, 8.0, 8.0, 6.75, 14.5, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0]",34,2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My aim is to have this last chart but with the solid orange and blue replaced with the stacks of color from the above two images.

One option could be to plot both stacked histograms with a `rwidth` < 0.5 and then manually shift the x positions of the bars to have both histograms properly side by side.
Note that a solution using `align="left"` and `align="right"` does not seem to be easier here because of the `rwidth` < 1.

```py
middle_type1 = aa[aa['type']==1]['middle']
middle_type2 = aa[aa['type']==2]['middle']

rwidth = 0.4

*_, bars_mt1 = plt.hist(middle_type1, stacked=True, bins=range(25), rwidth=rwidth, align="left")
*_, bars_mt2 = plt.hist(middle_type2, stacked=True, bins=range(25), rwidth=rwidth, align="left")

# Flatten bar containers
bars_mt1 = [bar for bars in bars_mt1 for bar in bars]
bars_mt2 = [bar for bars in bars_mt2 for bar in bars]

# Shift the bars to the left or right side of the ticks
for bar in bars_mt1:
    x, y = bar.xy
    bar.set_x(x + rwidth/2)
        
for bar in bars_mt2:
    x, y = bar.xy
    bar.set_x(x - rwidth/2)
```

I think it'd also be nice to give an overall color palette to type 1 and type 2, if possible.

It is possible. Here is an example with `Blues` colormap for type 1 and `Reds` colormap for type 2.

```py
rcm = plt.get_cmap("Reds")
bcm = plt.get_cmap("Blues")

mt1_colors = rcm(np.linspace(0, 1, len(middle_type1)))
mt2_colors = bcm(np.linspace(0, 1, len(middle_type2)))

*_, bars_mt1 = plt.hist(..., color=mt1_colors)
*_, bars_mt2 = plt.hist(..., color=mt2_colors)
```

Adding `xticks` for each hour, here is the result.

[image]

Hope it matches what you want.

Comment: This is perfect- I was thinking this could be one solution, but had no idea how to execute on it. Out of curiosity, did you use a different dataset or a subset of the data? It looks like the peaks in this image (specifically at ~10 on the x axis) don't quite match up. Again, I greatly appreciate you answering all of my questions!

Comment: I used the subset provided in the question (35 lines df).